# How to change snake_case column names when loading data with dlt?

Tags: dlt

I am extracting data from Hubspot and loading into BigQuery with dlt. The column names are being automatically changed to snake_case e.g. createdAt being converted to created_at. How can I stop this happening?

So far I have tried:

1. Defining a pydantic model for the columns parameter
2. Editing both the `import/hubspot.schema.yaml` and `export/hubspot.schema.yaml` schema files column names and also changing normalizers names to direct. The schema file seems to be overwritten though, and quite sporadically. dlt also seems to take no notice of these files so not sure I am using them correctly